# cordova can't move to next page in the app?

Tags: cordova

In my app I have a main page with a list of items. When you click on the item it needs to go to the detail page.

My click looks like this, which seems to be working

```
$('.animalClick').on('click tap', function (e) {
     var link = 'detail.html/' + $(this).attr("data-id");
     window.open(link);
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

However, when going to that link I get in the browser

Cannot GET /detail.html/8630969

and in the console it says

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Which has me confused because I do have a detail.html and in the config.xml I have

```
<allow-navigation href="detail:*" />
```

Any idea's what I'm missing?

Comment: You can't use dynamic page unless you do capture yourself. Do you have a page for each data-id ??

Comment: @Eric, what do you mean capture? I don't have a page for each data id, I was trying to use that as a way to pass what id they clicked on so I can get the proper data. This is not possible? Is there a better way to do this? When I take the id out of the url it still produces the same error

Comment: Not out of the box because this is HTML only. You don't have a server environment to handle the query strings like you're trying to do. You need to go with a framework for that, only I know of that can do that is https://github.com/globules-io/OGX.JS